Newtonsoft - Deserialize JSON ignore underline without JsonProperty
I have a JSON like this:
{
    "part_1": "",
    "part_2": "",
    "part_3": "",
    "part_4": "",
    "part_5": "",
    "part_6": "",
    "part_7": "",
    "part_8": "",
    "part_9": "",
    "part_10": "",
    "part_11": "",
    "part_12": "",
    "totalNum": "",
    "ab_cd_ef": ""
}

I want to deserialize this JSON and remove their underscores like this:
public partial class Welcome4
{
    public string Part1 { get; set; }
    public string Part2 { get; set; }
    public string Part3 { get; set; }
    ......
    public int TotalNum { get; set; }
    public string Abcdef { get; set; }
}

Using JsonProperty requires writing too many annotations. Is there any simpler way?
I tried to use DefaultContractResolver but could not find the relevant interface and could only operate on properties.
I tried to find a similar solution, but couldn't find it.
jsonKey.Replace("_", "")

I found a barely acceptable method:
string pattern = @"\""([^\""]*)\""\s*(?=:)";
string newJson = Regex.Replace(json, pattern, m => m.Value.ToLower().Replace("_", ""));
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(newJson);


Does this answer your question? ContractResolver, lowercase with underscore (snake case property names)?

This seems to be matching the attribute name by word segmentation. It cannot handle JSON with mixed camel case and snake case, and cannot handle JSON that is not separated by underscores based on words.

It cannot handle JSON with mixed camel case and snake case -- your question does show mixed camel and snake case, please clarify.

public int totalnum { get; set; } - w h y would you violate C#-Naming conventions for this one property and not the others?

Did your question get answered?  If your C# property names can be mapped to JSON property names with underscores according to some rule, then @YongShun's answer is the way to go.  But if the JSON property names are sprinkled with underscores without any discernible pattern and you only need to deserialize, you could subclass JsonTextReader.  Do you need an answer showing how to do that?

If you do just want to strip all underscores from property names unconditionally while reading, you could use PropertyNameMappingJsonReader from this answer to Change key name of data loaded through JsonExtensionData with nameMapper: n => n.Replace("_", "").

From this raised GitHub issue: NamingStrategy: Support numbers as words option, there is no support for treating the number as a word.
Thus, the SnakeCaseNamingStrategy is not working in your scenario.
Either you can customize the existing SnakeCaseNamingStrategy as proposed commit.
Or you should implement your own naming strategy to add the separator in between the alphabetic character and number.
For my implemented custom NamingStrategy class, it inherits the SnakeCaseNamingStrategy and working with regex expression to add the separator between the alphabetic character and number.
public class SnakeCaseWithNumberNamingStrategy : SnakeCaseNamingStrategy
{
    private readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[A-Za-z])");
    private readonly char separator = '_';
    
    public SnakeCaseWithNumberNamingStrategy(bool processDictionaryKeys, bool overrideSpecifiedNames)
        : base(processDictionaryKeys, overrideSpecifiedNames)
    {
        ProcessDictionaryKeys = processDictionaryKeys;
        OverrideSpecifiedNames = overrideSpecifiedNames;
    }

    public SnakeCaseWithNumberNamingStrategy(bool processDictionaryKeys, bool overrideSpecifiedNames, bool processExtensionDataNames) : this(processDictionaryKeys, overrideSpecifiedNames)
    {
        ProcessExtensionDataNames = processExtensionDataNames;
    }

    public SnakeCaseWithNumberNamingStrategy()
    {
    }

    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string name)
    {
        return ResolvePropertyNameWithNumber(base.ResolvePropertyName(name));
    }
    
    private string ResolvePropertyNameWithNumber(string name)
    {        
        string formattedName = regex.Replace(name, separator.ToString());
        
        return formattedName;
    }
}

Next, ensure that you add the SnakeCaseWithNumberNamingStrategy in the JsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver.
DefaultContractResolver contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseWithNumberNamingStrategy(),
};
Welcome4 model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome4>(json, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = contractResolver });

Updated
As mentioned in the question, there is a field that does not apply the snake case format, for the special case, would suggest using the [JsonProperty] attribute which is simpler. There is no naming strategy or contract resolver that supports (de)serialization in multiple patterns/formats at the same time.
Note that your Abcdef property will not deserialize correctly as you do not name it correctly according to the snake case name. The first character after the underscore is needed to be capitalized.
public partial class Welcome4
{
    public string Part1 { get; set; }
    public string Part2 { get; set; }
    public string Part3 { get; set; }

    ...

    [JsonProperty("totalNum")]
    public int TotalNum { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ab_cd_ef")]
    public string Abcdef { get; set; }

    // Or
    // public string AbCdEf { get; set; }
}


Demo @ .NET Fiddle
